# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object error (Asset management system)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My whole project has been fully functional except for the create feature. When I'm logged on as a regular user, I can view the index of the clothes without any problem. But when logged on as an admin, I can only view the index when I create a new clothe for the first time (which regular user doesn't have access to).

After that first time, the second time I add a new clothe, this error pops up, and I'm trying to figure this out. I'm just starting out with Laravel.

This is the code inside my index function on the controller:

```
$clothe = Clothe::all();

return view('clothes.index')->with('clothe',$clothe)->with('brand',Brand::all())->with('stock',Stock::all());
```

The brand pertains to the brand model which is the brands of clothing, while stock is the stock model which pertains to 2 pieces of data, 'Available' and 'Not Available' (take note this works when I'm only logged in as a regular user, but doesn't when I create a second clothe as an admin)

On my clothes index blade, for some reason it reads $brand, $stock and $clothe as non objects.

When the admin creates the second clothing, the data does get stored as I have checked in my database, the only problem is displaying it.

This is my store function:

```
public function store(Request $request, Clothe $clothe, Stock $stock)
{
    $this->authorize('create',$clothe,$stock);
        $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'brand-id' => 'required|numeric',
        'stock-id' => 'required|numeric',
        'description' => 'required|string',
        'image' => 'required|image|max:5000'
    ]);

    $clothe = new Clothe;

    $clothe->name = $request->input('name');
    $clothe->price = $request->input('price');
    $clothe->brand_id = $request->input('brand-id');
    $clothe->stock_id = $request->input('stock-id');
    $clothe->status_id = 1;
    $clothe->description = $request->input('description');
    $clothe->image = $request->image->store('public');

    $clothe->save();

    return redirect(route('clothes.index'));
}
```

and this is my create function

```
public function create(Clothe $clothe)
{
    $this->authorize('create',$clothe);
    $brand = Brand::all();
    $stock = Stock::all();
    return view('clothes.create')->with('brand',$brand)->with('stock',$stock);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling id? Myabe show us the index itself and the create blade.

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/dmkjlD53 this is the link to the full error stack, the index code is there

Comment: It's weird the error is about id but at the link it says on line 46 where there is no id.
Do you know which of the calls to the id is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing this

Line: 34

```
@foreach($clothe as $clothe)
```

I dunno if this is what is confusing PHP into sometimes treating '$clothes' as the collection instead of the instance because you are using the same variable name, it should be :

```
@foreach($clothes as $clothe) 
OR
@foreach($clothe as $singleclothe)
```

OR

$clothe->stock->id needs to be $clothe->stock()->id dependent on relationship, because you can only call that on eloquent relationships or functions that return a relationship instance else you need to use ().

Comment: HOLY &%$# THANK U SO MUCH IT WORKED! I can't believe what an effect naming has :(